# Is there a way to attach a profiler in Netbeans on a Tomcat 7 server?

Tags: profiler, tomcat7, netbeans-7, netbeans-plugins, vs-web-application-project

I have been unable to start my tomcat 7 instance using the Netbeans 7 profiler. is there a setup that will alow this to work? I have tried a few different settings as well as trying to attach to a "generic webapp server". I only see the options up to Tomcat 6 but I feel that 7 has been out long enough to be able to profile it.

If Netbeans cannot then is there a plugin or 3rd party that can?